# Keep getting traceback call for app.run() in Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, traceback

So I'm working on this project that I'm using Flask for and I'm still new to using Flask. However, whenever I try running the script I'm using for this project I get a traceback call complaining about app.run().

Here's the code from my script:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle
from flask_wtf import Form 
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

CSRF_ENABLED = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key'
assets = Environment(app)
assets.url = app.static_url_path
scss = Bundle('assets/scss/app.scss', filters='scss', output='css/app.css')
assets.register('app_scss', scss)

@app.route('/')
def server_1():
     return render_template('server_1.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run()
```

Here's the traceback that the script keeps outputting (I spaced out the individual tracebacks to make them easier to read):

```
$python app.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "app.py", line 22, in <module>
   app.run()

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.6-  py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 710, in run_simple
 inner()

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in inner
passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 486, in make_server
passthrough_errors, ssl_context)

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 410, in __init__
HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
self.server_bind()

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

I'm not too sure what I did wrong so any help that can be given is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something else is already running on port 5000. Do you have another Flask app running already?

Comment: No, I didn't have anything else running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

Indicates that you already have something else running on 127.0.0.1 port 5000.

To find out what process is using this address, you can run the following command (on OS X)

```
lsof -i tcp:5000
```

Alternatively, if you wish to use a different port, say 5001, adjust your code as such:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(port=5001)
```

Comment: It worked thanks. It looks like python is already using port 5000 for something, but I'm not sure what is using that port.

Comment: alternatively, do `app.run(port=8080)`